# Zorba collections: a simple directory of xml files

Tags: collections, xquery, zorba

I have a directory of xml files I'd like to use as a collection, specifically, to look at `$my_collection/of/things` where each file has `<things>`.

I am using Zorba.

This results in `error retrieving resource` (syntax problem?):

`variable $my_collection := fn:collection("file://localhost/path/to/my/*.xml");`

I also read over the documentation on Zorba's [Data Definition Facility](http://www.zorba.io/documentation/2.9/zorba/xqddf.html)... seems like overkill for this singular purpose.  Or, not?

Comment: using Saxon I just say `declare variable $my_collection := collection("/path/to/my/xml_directory");`  Zorba returns "error retrieving resource" for this as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edited question - putting everything into an actual Zorba collection as opposed to a nodelist. You might want to choose between static and dynamic collections for your purposes.

**F.xq:**

```
module namespace X = "urn:xml-files";
import module namespace ddl = "http://www.zorba-xquery.com/modules/store/static/collections/ddl";
import module namespace dml = "http://www.zorba-xquery.com/modules/store/static/collections/dml";
import module namespace file = "http://expath.org/ns/file";
import module namespace x = "http://www.zorba-xquery.com/modules/xml";
declare namespace ann = "http://www.zorba-xquery.com/annotations";

declare collection X:files as node()*;
declare variable $X:uri := xs:QName('X:files');

declare %ann:nondeterministic function X:get-xml-list($dir-name as xs:string) {
    let $files := file:list($dir-name, true())
    for $filename in $files
    where ends-with($filename, ".xml")
    return $filename
};
declare %ann:sequential function X:load-files($names as xs:string*) {
    ddl:create($X:uri);
    dml:insert-nodes($X:uri, for $filename in $names return x:parse(file:read-text($filename),()));
};
declare %ann:sequential function X:load-directory($dir-name as xs:string) {
    X:load-files(X:get-xml-list($dir-name))
};
```

**x.xq:**

```
xquery version "3.0" encoding "utf-8";
import module namespace X = "urn:xml-files" at "F.xq";
import module namespace dml = "http://www.zorba-xquery.com/modules/store/static/collections/dml";
X:load-directory("C:\Projects-dir...-with-xmls\");
dml:collection($X:uri)
```

References:

- http://www.zorba.io/documentation/2.9/zorba/xqddf.html
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zorba_(XQuery_processor)
- http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-ends-with
- http://www.zorba.io/documentation/2.9/modules/expath.org_ns_file.html
- [create collection, add document to zorba using command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13026559/create-collection-add-document-to-zorba-using-command-line)

Comment: No; rather, `collection` should read the node tree from each file and bind to a single variable, as if it was all one big file in the first place.

Comment: Hi @Pete, is this what you want? I've edited - now everything gets loaded into a collection.

Comment: +1 great example of how to use Zorba collections to achieve this goal.  The question remains, are Zorba collections required?  Or is there some way to get a one-liner collection as we can with Saxon?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
collection("file:///localhost/path/to/my?select=*.xml;recurse=yes")
```

Comment: I sill get `error retrieving resource` from Zorba with this.  I know there's nothing wrong with the path, because the same path works with Saxon.

Answer (score 1):

Solution added by user Scala William is the way to go but his solution is a bit outdated. Here's his code updated for zorba 3.0:

**F.xq**:

```
module namespace X = "urn:xml-files";
import module namespace ddl = "http://zorba.io/modules/store/static/collections/ddl";
import module namespace dml = "http://zorba.io/modules/store/static/collections/dml";
import module namespace fs = "http://expath.org/ns/file";
import module namespace x = "http://zorba.io/modules/xml";
declare namespace an = "http://zorba.io/annotations";

declare collection X:files as node()*;
declare variable $X:uri := xs:QName('X:files');

declare %an:nondeterministic function X:get-xml-list($dir-name as xs:string)
{
    let $files := fs:list($dir-name, fn:false(),"*.xml")
    for $filename in $files
    return concat($dir-name,$filename)
};

declare %an:sequential function X:load-files($names as xs:string*)
{
    ddl:create($X:uri);
    dml:insert($X:uri, for $filename in $names return x:parse(fs:read-text($filename),()));
};

declare %an:sequential function X:load-directory($dir-name as xs:string)
{
    X:load-files(X:get-xml-list($dir-name))
};
```

Please note the call to concat(...) instead of just $filename in the return at X:get-xml-list(). Also, the call to insert-nodes(...) has changed to insert(...) at X:load-files().

Also please consider changing fn:false() to fn:true() in fs:list(...) at X:get-xml-list() if you need your listing recursive.

Comment: Hi, I am using zorba 3.1. I am receiving the following error:
`</home/eadaradhiraj/Documents/q1>:3,1: static error [err:XQST0059]: module "http://www.zorba-xquery.com/modules/store/static/collections/dml" not found at location "http://www.zorba-xquery.com/modules/store/static/collections/dml" : "http://www.zorba-xquery.com/modules/store/static/collections/dml.module": Could not create stream resource
`